# Still can't upgrade? Is there a new delay?

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, do-release-upgrade

As of 8/2 I'm still unable to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 using the do-release-upgrade command. Still "No new release found." I don't remember it ever taking this long before. And I'd rather not use -d , cause I want to stay on the LTS.

I know they said it'd be a few days, but it's been like a week.. Was there an unexpected delay or something?

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  From a technical perspective, the UpdateManager.Core.MetaRelease which do-release-upgrade uses calls https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts which doesn't yet have 18.04.1 listed.

Comment: @karel I think the OP is asking a political question.  Some insight may also be found here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+milestone/ubuntu-18.04.1  Despite being released, there appear to be a small number of major bugs still open.

Comment: It's not as if I'm not blindly asking why the update isn't working just a couple days after the release.. It's been a full week, and there hasn't even been any announcements, just the "it takes a few days" excuse.. So I'm just wondering if anyone has information about an actual delay. Those other posts aren't asking that.

EDIT: Oh, I see, there might still be some bugs they're trying to fix? That's at least some news, better than I was able to find on my own. thx at least. heh

Comment: @nik it will arrive when it arrives.

Comment: @tudor Because Canonical wants people to use their software, sometimes they have to postpone a launch date because if they release a version that has bugs in it some users will give up and stop using it.

Comment: fyi:  it hasn't been a week yet; nearly a week yes but we're still a number of hours from a week on the official [18.04.1] notice (https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2018-July/000234.html)

Comment: @karel I think the real question is if Canonical has released the point release and LTS upgrades are enabled when the point release is released, why would they not yet enabled the LTS upgrade path?  To which the answer may lie in the bug list.

Comment: @Nik some of us have customers who demand timelines to be respected. Especially when they planned the systems upgrade during mid-August employees vacations.

Comment: Upgrade was released today (August 15, 2018), by the way. :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, as mentioned in other questions:

1. LTS upgrades don't occur until the first point release.  This is because Canonical prefers to let things settle before sending the release to automatically upgraded systems - usually servers, and usually in HUGE numbers, which will have an effect not just on Canonical's server load but also on SysAdmins worldwide and Canonical's support team.*
2. Automated server installs occur during the period after a point release and before an upgrade.  These are smaller numbers of servers but still significant compared to numbers before the point release.**

However, more importantly, from gleaning [the URL do-release-upgrade calls](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts) and its content, I suspect **the LTS upgrade list is not architecture-specific**, and also from the current list of [open bugs against the 18.04.1 point release](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+milestone/ubuntu-18.04.1) some of those bugs are specific arch bugs.

Needless to say, it's in Canonical's interest to release when these things work and *not sooner*.

**Patience is a virtue.** :-)

* Take it from a SysAdmin, you can be up for days fixing little kinks when this happens, so you want to be damn sure it goes smoothly.

** SysAdmins are a cautious bunch, so we don't tend to put even LTS first cuts into production, but we will push LTS to new installs after the first point release

Comment: Additional information released on Friday: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2018-August/004556.html  Release should be out in another week.

Comment: Upgrade was released today (August 15, 2018). :)