# Upgrade to 18.04 from 16.04 still not available?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04

It's my understanding that upgrades from Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 18 should be enabled after the 18.04.1 release. According to [the release schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule), this release came out on July 26.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.5. I've run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Then, I try to run

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

However, this fails. The output is:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.
```

Can anyone explain next steps? I've been browsing recent questions, and it seems that others have managed the upgrade. I'll be happy to post other relevant system info if needed.

This is not a duplicate of the [suggested thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061685/still-cant-upgrade-is-there-a-new-delay), because the upgrade is actually available now. Anyway, I have written my own answer to the question already.

Comment: read through this thread which you may find helpful... https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/07/ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to **Software and Updates > Updates**, then set it to notify me of a new Ubuntu version for any new version.

Then I restarted. After that, the commands above worked for me.